# How to play youtube in portrait full screen mode when use WKWebView

Tags: swift3

I have upgraded to iOS 11.0.3 for my mobile phone. It seems before upgrading, I kind of able to play Youtube in portrait in fullscreen mode but now I was not able to do so. I am not sure which is which.

In my code, I use the following in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
 let webviewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webviewConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
```

for the URL :

```
let usrl = URL(string: https://www.youtube.com.......+"?playsinline=1"
```

What I need to do.

Comment: it is ?playsinline = 1 or playinline =1  with or without the - s matters?